# Redirect output to a file while piping cat and perl

Tags: bash, pipe

I need to shuffle lines in a text file and store the result into a new text file.
This is the command I used. However, this prints the shuffled lines into the console not the outfile.

```
cat infile | perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e 'srand 123; print shuffle(<>);' "$@"; > outfile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the unprotected semicolon is the culprit

It just stops the current command and starts another empty one (creates an empty file).

note that the extra `"$@"`arguments of `perl` are useless here, and so is the use of `cat`. So to sum it all you could write:

```
perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e 'srand 123; print shuffle(<>);' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the last ; makes it work.

```
cat infile | perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e 'srand 123; print shuffle(<>);' "$@" > outfile
```